# Python: How do you find the first day of every month between two date ranges

Tags: python, datetime

I wrote some code to create a list of the first day of the month for every day between two date ranges. Can you think of a better way to do this?

```
import datetime
end_date= datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-03-28', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
start_date= datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-10-25', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
print(start_date)
print(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
mylist = []
checking_date = start_date
print(checking_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
while str(checking_date) < str(end_date):
    if checking_date != start_date:
        mylist.append(checking_date)
    month = str(checking_date).split('-')[1]
    new_date = checking_date + datetime.timedelta(days=20)
    possible_new_month = str(new_date).split('-')[1]
    if possible_new_month == month:
        new_date = new_date + datetime.timedelta(days=20)
    new_year = str(new_date).split('-')[0]
    new_month = str(new_date).split('-')[1]
    checking_date_format = "{0}-{1}-01".format(new_year,new_month)
    checking_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(checking_date_format, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Comment: So what's the expected output? November 2017, December 2017, January 2018, February 2018, and March 2018?

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to use `dateutil` modules [`rrule`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#rrule-examples) submodule for any kind of recurrence of date/time. You can install it by doing `pip install python-dateutil`

```
>>> from dateutil import rrule, parser
>>> start = parser.parse('Jan 10 2017')
>>> end   = parser.parse('Mar 5 2018')
>>> list(rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, bymonthday=1, dtstart=start, until=end))
[datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 9, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 11, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Small but perhaps important difference: you produce `datetime` objects, not `date`s.

Comment: Also, while nice and compact, `rrule()` is slow for this case as it has to account for much more complex recurrence rules.

Comment: I personally would prefer to reuse something from a existing well maintained module before writing my own code for maintainability reasons

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to reason about month-arithmetic if you convert the year and month to a single number, with `years * 12 + (month - 1)`; this can be converted back to a year and month pair by a floor division and modulus operation. For example, 2017-10 (October) is 24213 months since the year zero:

```
>>> 2017 * 12 + (10 - 1)
24213
```

You can trivially add to or remove a number of months from that figure. You can get the year out again by floor division, and the month is found with `%` modulus and adding back `1`:

```
>>> 24213 // 12  # year
2017
>>> (24213 % 12) + 1  # month
10
```

With this in mind, you can then use a `range()` to generate any number of months:

```
from datetime import date

def months(start_date, end_date, day=1):
    """Produce a date for every month from start until end"""
    start = start_date.year * 12 + (start_date.month - 1)
    if start_date.day > day:
        # already in this month, so start counting at the next
        start += 1
    end = end_date.year * 12 + (end_date.month - 1)
    if end_date.day > day:
        # end date is past the reference day, include the reference
        # date in the output
        end += 1
    # generate the months, just a range from start to end
    for ordinal in range(start, end):
        yield date(ordinal // 12, (ordinal % 12) + 1, day)
```

The above is a generator function that yields consecutive months; call `list()` on it if you need to have the complete sequence:

```
>>> start_date = date(2017, 10, 25)
>>> end_date = date(2018, 3, 28)
>>> list(months(start_date, end_date))
[datetime.date(2017, 11, 1), datetime.date(2017, 12, 1), datetime.date(2018, 1, 1), datetime.date(2018, 2, 1), datetime.date(2018, 3, 1)]
```

Note that at no point do you need to convert dates to strings! You can trivially get the month value from the instance by using the `.month` attribute.

To make a comparison, I've converted the other two solutions to be generators too:

```
from calendar import monthrange
from datetime import timedelta
from dateutil import rrule

def andray_timedelta_one(start_date, end_date):
    delta = end_date - start_date
    first_days_of_month = []
    for i in range(delta.days + 1):
        d = start_date + timedelta(i)
        if d.day == 1:
            yield d

def matthew_timedelta_monthrange(start_date, end_date):
    if start_date.day == 1:
        yield start_date

    start_date = start_date.replace(day=1)

    while start_date <= end_date:
        # add the number of days in the month for this month/year
        try:
            start_date += timedelta(monthrange(start_date.year, start_date.month)[1])
            yield start_date
        except OverflowError:
            # trying to add to close-to-date.max would raise this exception
            return

def sunitha_rrule(start_date, end_date):
    # already an iterable
    return rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, bymonthday=1, dtstart=start_date, until=end_date)

# for completion's sake, I renamed mine to martijn_months
```

That way their performance can be compared fairly, and we can use a `deque(..., maxlen=0)` trick to quickly consume their output without requiring huge amounts of memory. We can then run each of the functions over the range `date.min` through to `date.max`, the maximum possible range of dates; that's nearly 120 thousand date objects to produce:

```
>>> sum(1 for _ in months(datetime.date.min, datetime.date.max))
119988
```

These are the results:

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> from collections import deque
>>> bootstrap = 'from __main__ import date, deque, {} as test'
>>> test = 'deque(test(date.min, date.max), maxlen=0)'
>>> for f in (
...         andray_timedelta_one,
...         sunitha_rrule,
...         matthew_timedelta_monthrange,
...         martijn_months):
...     loop_count, total_time = Timer(test, bootstrap.format(f.__name__)).autorange()
...     print(f'{f.__name__:<30}: {total_time/loop_count*1000:.5f}ms')
...
andray_timedelta_one          : 2001.27048ms
sunitha_rrule                 : 1517.70081ms
matthew_timedelta_monthrange  : 154.68727ms
martijn_months                : 38.86803ms
```

As you can see, my approach is orders of magnitude faster.

- Andray's approach wastes a huge amount of time creating every date in the calendar, adding one day at a time.
- The `rrule` approach Sunitha picked is nice and concise, but the function has to account for much more complex date arithmetic, and so this very simple case is not optimised. This makes `rrule()` *slow*!
- Matthew is a lot more efficient, but the calculations that `calendar.monthrange()` executes are still overkill for a simple plus-one operation on a year-month combination. We don't need to know if the current month has 31, 30, 29 or 28 days to make this calculation!

Answer (score 0):

The `datetime` class support arithmetic operations (you can do `+`, `-`, etc.). If you combine it with `timedelta`, you can **get all days** between `start_date` and `end_date`. Then searching for first day of month is easy:

```
import datetime
start_date= datetime.datetime.strptime('2017-10-25', "%Y-%m-%d").date()
end_date= datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-03-28', "%Y-%m-%d").date()

delta = end_date - start_date

first_days_of_month = []
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    d = start_date + datetime.timedelta(i)
    if d.day == 1:
        first_days_of_month.append(d)

print('start date =', start_date)
print('end date =', end_date)
for d in first_days_of_month:
    print(d, end=' ')
print()
```

Prints:

```
start date = 2017-10-25
end date = 2018-03-28
2017-11-01 2017-12-01 2018-01-01 2018-02-01 2018-03-01
```

Comment: This is *hugely* inefficient, executing 30 times more work than is needed, just to add a month to a date.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OPs question wasn't about efficiency, it was about getting an answer that he will understand. If this will be a bottleneck in his design, the problem will be somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, but answers here need to take into account that they'll be widely copied and pasted. My answer is no more difficult to understand but also doesn't create `date()` objects for every single day in the month. That's just a waste of computer cycles and memory.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's point of view...I think your answer is harder to understand, but I don't downvote you. What for? Lets op decide, what answer will chose. I could edit my answer and write that this will create every day between start_date and end_date, but that's just detail.

Comment: For example, the code in my answer can go from `datetime.date.min` through to `datetime.date.max` 100 times in 4 seconds flat. Your code barely completes 2 runs through in the same time. It is 50 times slower.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I know your answer is super efficient, but I'm repeating myself: lets op decide what answer suits for him better - me, myself, I prefer code that I understand. If something is bottlenecking, I profile the code, find the slow part and fix it, standard procedure.

Comment: I don't find this particularly easy to understand, fwiw, it's also very inefficient ... especially when you can get the # of days in the month from `calendar.monthrange` which is my preferred (and posted) solution.

Comment: @MatthewStory Yes, I see. I didn't know about `calendar.monthrange`, so today I learned new thing. thanks. I upvoted your answer :)

Comment: @AndrejKesely: yes, and I can still voice my opinion about your approach. You are then free to take that advice on board or ignore it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes of course, the comments under answers are for exactly this reason. To voice opinion.